# How do I make certain images have a certain width and not others?

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress, image-scaling

I recently changed the width of my [Wordpress site](http://weeabooswithcontrollers.com/2013/04/29/gears-of-war-judgment-review-a-solid-change-of-direction/) from 456px wide to 620px. Of course this has resulted in all of my images now not fitting to the new width. I discovered that by using the following code, it almost solves my problem.

```
p img {

width: 100% !important;

height: auto;

}
```

The issue I'm having is that a set of images used in multiple locations (a star rating system) is meant to be small and using the above code forces them to enlarge and screws them up. How can I use the above code to apply to my images in all of my posts, except for a handful of star images that I don't want enlarged? Thanks for your time and I appreciate the help.

*Updated my question for clarity*

Comment: Is this star image used in one HTML element or to multiple ?

Comment: It is used in multiple locations, which is why I'm trying to avoid having to manually go in and change each one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSS class, to your img that doesn't belong to this rule like.

CSS

```
.star-img{
    width: auto;
}
```

Another example

```
p img.star-img{
    width: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="star.jpg" alt="Star" class="star-img">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I think I follow. The image is found on multiple posts, though, so would I need to insert that HTML into each one manually to make the exception? Or can I set up a CSS class to simply apply site wide and just add it to my stylesheet?

Comment: In the best scenario you could do both, but following your link http://weeabooswithcontrollers.com/2012/03/24/review-shadows-of-the-damned/score-4-0/ , you can't use a rule for only that star without adding the class for your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of both general and selected styling.

```
img {width:620px;}
#exceptional_image {width:360px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not very good with CSS. How would I set up the "#exceptional_image" class and where do I insert it? For example, this is the url of the image: http://weeabooswithcontrollers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Score-4.0.png

Comment: You are most welcome. Suppose, you want to style different for facebook image. Do the following coding:
<img id ="exceptional image" src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" />
img {width:620px;}
#exceptional_image {width:360px;}

Comment: Interesting. To be clear, where would I declare that ID? Do I copy all code to my style.css or does it need to go somewhere else?

Comment: Simply copy my css styles in your style.css